# How to findViewById in RecyclerView after setting custom id to every element via adapter

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have a fragment that implements Recycler View with switches. RecyclerView sets id for every switch in id+=1 way. The problem is I can get nothing from these IDs as soon as calling throws NullableException. I understand that I have to call it correctly from parent, but I don`t get how to do it correctly.
There is the structure of code:
Fragment with ConstraintLayout(R.id.settingsScreen) -> RecylerView(R.id.recyclerView), that creates LinearLayouts(R.id.settingLayout) with switches(R.id.switch).

```
class ViewHolder{
    val l : LinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.settingLayout)
}

if (holder.l.findViewById<SwitchCompat>(1100).isActivated){..}
```

throws `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.isActivated()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 1):

It is very fragile to create view IDs yourself like this. They could easily collide with IDs generated by the Android build. So if you create IDs, you should be using [`ViewCompat.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ViewCompat#generateViewId()) to do it safely.

But `findViewById` is something you generally want to avoid in the first place. It is slow. That's why View Binding is provided, to cache the views so you don't have to keep searching for them.

I highly recommend storing your Views in a collection instead of assigning them IDs. Then you can efficiently pull them from the collection when you need them. You just need to be sure the collection will be garbage collected when you're done with the views (don't create a collection that will outlive the screen the views are on).

Comment: Ok, i admit that using ids was the bad idea. Thank you for your answer, i will change my code to correspond with better variant of working with adapters. (Unfourtunately, I cannot up your reputation, but I am sincerely thank you)

Answer (score 0):

## You can get the view by using itemView property

Not sure of you are trying to do when you mean custom id.

---

You can get all views inflated by viewHolder with itemView.

this property is given to ViewHolder after you pass view as parameter in ViewHolder constructor, than ViewHolder will inflate views according with their id's.

than you can get view inside ViewHolder by:

```
itemView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.settingLayout)

itemView.findViewById<SwitchCompat>(R.id.switch)
```

You can look to see more options in [google docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview#implement-adapter)

If these are not what you asked for please let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn`t help. By custom id i mean setting id for each switch in OnBindViewHolder with the help of var id: 1100; id++. In my app I need to check if 1100/1101/1102/1103 is activated, but it always throws NullPointerException despite all of them have their own IDs(Checked this with holder.switch.setOnClickListener{Log.d("x", "${item.id}")})

Comment: Can you find some exemples setting id's programmatically or setting by number will work?

Comment: Yes, it works in my app in one place, but does not in another. However, i find out that setting custom IDs is the bad practice so I`m gonna remove them and try to do it in another way. Thank you for the help